# Sacar el % de cumplimiento de una columna en Power BI

Tags: sql-server, excel, powerbi

Estoy haciendo una columna calculada en Power BI que se llama Cumplimiento, la columna es formada de la siguiente manera:

```
    Cumplimiento = IF('SLA Service Now'[Ha producido una infracción]=FALSE(),(
DIVIDE(COUNT('SLA Service Now'[Status SLA]),[Conteo de tickets],90)))
```

Si yo muestro solo los siguientes datos, la tabla se muestra de manera correcta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si agrego el campo de Cumplimiento no se realiza el calculo y la tabla se visualiza de mala manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea o sugerencia que me pudieran dar me vendría muy bien.

Saludos.

Comment: Parece un problema de servicio al cliente de PowerBI.

Comment: Valida si es necesario el uso de la agregación COUNT() en la definición del campo calculado. Parece que no es necesaria... Adicionalmente, ¿esto debe mostrarse como un porcentaje, correcto?

Comment: @alanfcm No. Está haciendo una pregunta sobre código, tan válida como cualquier otra.

Answer (score 1):

Apenas estoy iniciándome en este mundillo e imagino que ya habrás encontrado la solución, pero creo que te podría venir bien usar la función CALCULATE.
'CALCULATE ( Expresión; [Filtro 1]; [Filtro2]; … )'

La fórmula quedaría así:

`Cumplimiento = CALCULATE(DIVIDE(COUNT('SLA Service Now'[Status SLA]),[Conteo de tickets],90),'SLA Service Now'[Ha producido una infracción]=FALSE())`

Esta página da información bastante completa acerca de la función CALCULATe por si interesa:
[CALCULATE en DAX: La Reina de las Funciones](https://www.excelfreeblog.com/calculate-dax-la-reina-las-funciones/)